# Undefined variable row

Tags: php

Please Help Undefined variable row, im trying to figure it out why row in undefined.
filename is UpdateProfile1.php

```
if(isset($_GET['UpdateProfile1']))
{ 
  $studid       =   $_GET['edit'];
  $res      =   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM personneldo WHERE studid='$studid'");
  //i already declared it 
  $row      =   mysql_fetch_array($res);
}
if(isset($_POST['newName']))
{
  $newName=     $_POST['newName'];
  $studid = $_POST['studid'];
  $sql  =   "UPDATE personneldo SET FirstName='$newName' WHERE studid='$studid'";
  //please help
  $res  =   mysql_query($sql) or die ("could not update".mysql_error());}

  //form 
  <form action="UpdateProfile1.php" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="newName" value="<?php echo $row[1]; ?>"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="studid" value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Comment: Look at your HTML source; it's just as good a tool.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Strange. I don't even know where the HTML is.

Comment: CODE INDENTATION PLEASE! Its not assembler

Comment: The mysql_* extension is deprecated, see http://docs.php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing . Also consult a basic php/mysql tutorial that shows you how to fetch the records/rows from the result resource returned by mysql_query() [or better mysqli_query]

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari it's on "their" end ;-)

Comment: [***Please don't do that.............***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541250/undefined-variable-row#comment52939704_32541250) put that in your question then delete it from "comments".

Comment: @Fred-ii- look what he just did. I'll catch my train to lala-land now.

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari I'll be on the E-train myself.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array() return an associative array. use the field name in db to fetch the data. let's say the field in the db are id, stud_name,

```
----------------------
|  id   |  stud_name |
----------------------
|  s1   |   abc      |
----------------------
|  s2   |   xyz      | 
----------------------
```

the you should use

```
 $row["id"];
$row["stud_name"];
```

istead of

```
$row[0];
$row[1];
```

Comment: The default value for the second parameter `type` of mysql_fetch_array() is `MYSQL_BOTH` for which the returned array contains both the positional _and_ the named fields.